# How to use derived attributes in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working with Core Data. I have a field called `date` that could contain a date or nil.

I want to make a second field called `sortDate` that will use the date value from the `date` field if there is one. If the `date` field is nil, I want to return the current date. I need this to be a core data attribute (not a computed property) because I need to sort fetched records based on this value.

I think the way to do this is with derived attributes but I can't find any information on **how** to use them. I selected the checkbox called "Derived". This shows the "Derivation expression" field, but I have no idea what to enter here. There is no link to documentation on the Xcode UI.

Despite the comment below, I cannot locate any documentation for this feature. I've searched the documentation many times and can't find a single word from Apple about this other than [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/) where they *mention* documentation but do not link to it to say how to find it.

I'm not the only one failing to find this: [Documentation on core data derived attributes](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120159)

Comment: Pros and cons of derived attributes are well documented on this and other web sites. Watch the WWDC 2019 session "[Making Apps With Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/)" at approximately 18:00 in for a good overview of Core Data managed derived attributes. You've not mentioned the volume of data you'll be recalling (do you or are you experiencing performance problems?) so it will be difficult to provide advice as to "needs of controller vs needs of model". Are you using an `NSFetchedResultsController`? Have you tried building compound predicates?

Comment: I don't see derived attributes anywhere on the Core Data documentation. Not a single mention of them. The documentation mentioned in the video does not seem to exist either.I don't expect high volume or performance issues. I see the new checkbox and field in the Xcode inspector but can find no information on using those features. I can't answer what haven't tried because as I said "I'm not sure where to start" as in I really don't know, not "I've tried stuff but don't want to tell you"

Comment: Looks like Apple finally posted some basic documentation for this. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used in the past and has always worked for me is to add it as a property in the model and then update it programmatically on `willSave`.

For example:

```
@objc(MyCoreDataModelObject)
class MyCoreDataModelObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var date: Date?

    override func willSave() {
        setPrimitiveValue(
            date.map { ISO8601DateFormatter().string(from: $0) },
            forKey: "sortDate"
        )
    }
}
```

If you already have a version of your model with `date` then you also have to do separate code to generate the current `sortDate` for those.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the link @radicalappdev posted as a comment:

So you can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription) now.

Short answer is that it's *super* disappointing.  You scan either specify an attribute on the current entity or on the target of a to-one relationship using the forms

```
attrname
relationship.attrname
```

You can precede the above expressions with the operators canonical:, uppercase:, and lowercase:, e.g., lowercase:attrname.

Or you can count the objects in a to-many relationship or sum on of their attributes using the syntax

```
relationship.@count
relationship.attribute.@sum
```

That appears to be fucking all of it.  Yes, you can't even take the max as far as I can tell from other answers here.  It feels like someone built the framework for a decent feature and then left the company and it got forgotten.